# How can I create a table in a DOCX file with Python?

Tags: python, tkinter, ms-word, docx

I am trying to send selected values from radiobuttons into a `.docx` file

importing what I need, focus is on docx

```
import tkinter as tk
from docx import Document
main = tk.Tk()
```

these are my options that I need to place into a word document on the left of the table, they act as questions in a survey.

```
info = ["option 1", "option 2", "option 3", "option 4"
         ]
```

Here I am placing radiobuttons called `Yes, No & N/A` which are answers to the options on the left(list of `info` above) and also `Label` to represent options or in other words questions..

```
vars = []
for idx,i in enumerate(info):
    var = tk.IntVar(value=0)
    vars.append(var)
    lblOption = tk.Label(main,text=i)
    btnYes = tk.Radiobutton(main, text="Yes", variable=var, value=2)
    btnNo = tk.Radiobutton(main, text="No", variable=var, value=1)
    btnNa = tk.Radiobutton(main, text="N/A", variable=var,value=0)
    lblOption.grid(column=0,row=idx)
    btnYes.grid(column=1,row=idx)
    btnNo.grid(column=2,row=idx)
    btnNa.grid(column=3,row=idx)
```

Here is my function, creating a document and saving is the easy part. My issue is that I am muddled up creating a table that will have; Options on the left (from `info`) at the top are the headers (see RadioButtons `yes, no, & N/a`). And selected data, as an example, if for `option 1` I have selected No, then save the data into a `.docx` file with the one been selected **(See example bottom of page at Desired output).**

```
def send():
    document = Document()
    section = document.sections[0]
    #add table
    table = document.add_table(1, 4)
    #style table
    table.style = 'Table Grid'

    #table data retrived from Radiobuttons
    items = vars.get()

    #populate header row
    heading_cells = table.rows[0].cells
    heading_cells[0].text = "Options"
    heading_cells[1].text = btnYes.cget("text")
    heading_cells[2].text = btnNo.cget("text")
    heading_cells[3].text = btnNa.cget("text")

    for item in items:
        cells = table.add_row().cells
        cells[0].text = #Options
        cells[1].text = #Yes values
        cells[2].text = #No values
        cells[3].text = #N/A values
    #save doc
    document.save("test.docx")

#button to send data to docx file
btn = tk.Button(main, text="Send to File", command= send)
btn.grid()

main.mainloop()
```

this is what it opens up:

[image]

Here is the desired output:

[image]

Number `1` represents selected items from the tkinter application. But will figure out how to change it to a tick box.

I am kinda confused where I am at, I am new using docx.. been trying to read the [documentation](https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/python-docx/latest/python-docx.pdf).. and this is where I digged my self a hole into.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. What you have said is "I have this program that does A, I am trying to do B. B does not work. How do I do B?" The only answer I can provide is to write the program for you. Which isn't a meaningful answer and isn't helpful to anyone. Can you please provide an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and a **clear** statement of your problem and what you have attempted to do to fix it?

Comment: So, your issue has nothing to do with writing information to files or tkinter. Do you simply need to know how to create a table in a .docx file from Python where your input is a list? So you have not provided a **minimal**, reproducible example.

Comment: tkinter is just an app to act as a survey and `.docx` file to act as evidence what has been inputted from tkinter. But YES, how to create a table based on my loops

Comment: Ok, so your question isn't "Tkinter How to save data to DOCX file using loops?", but actually "How can I create a table in a DOCX file with Python?"

Comment: for items, maybe change it to the following: `for i in vars:
            items = str(i.get())`

Comment: sorry @EthanField my English isn't first language, but I'll try get better.. does the rest make sense?

Comment: That's perfectly fine, but the question you've asked has almost no relevance to the actual problem you're trying to solve. You should try reading about [X/Y problems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/372286).

Comment: @EthanField let me come back to you on that one, and Ill improve my question

Answer (score 1):

In your current code, `vars` is a list of `IntVar`s. You want to get each value individually instead of `vars.get()`. Also when writing to docx file, you need both `info` and values of radiobuttons, to track them both you can use an index.

With minimal changes to your code, you can use something like this.

```
def send():
    ...
    ... 
    heading_cells[3].text = btnNa.cget("text")

    for idx, item in enumerate(vars):
        cells = table.add_row().cells
        cells[0].text = info[idx]  # gets the option name
        val = item.get()  #radiobutton value
        if val == 2:  # checks if yes
            cells[1].text = "1"
        elif val == 1:   # checks if no
            cells[2].text = "1"
        elif val == 0:   # checks if N/A
            cells[3].text = "1"

    #save doc
    document.save("test.docx")
```

or you can use a dictionary to map radiobuttons to cells.

```
valuesCells = {0: 3, 1: 2, 2: 1}  # value of radiobutton: cell to write
                                  # hard to read what's going on though
for idx, item in enumerate(vars):

    cells = table.add_row().cells
    cells[0].text = info[idx]  # gets the option name
    val = item.get()
    cells[valuesCells[val]].text = "1"

#save doc
document.save("test.docx")
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for late response. This is perfect! even tho I haven't yet edited my question..